Print pdf file -> annotations not printed to the paper
if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
    layoutResultCallback.onLayoutCancelled();
}
else {
    PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder=
            new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder("Contract");
    builder.setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
            .setPageCount(PrintDocumentInfo.PAGE_COUNT_UNKNOWN)
            .build();
    layoutResultCallback.onLayoutFinished(builder.build(),
            !printAttributes1.equals(printAttributes));
}

}
@Override
public void onWrite(PageRange[] pageRanges, ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback writeResultCallback) {
InputStream in=null;
OutputStream out=null;
try {
    File file = new File(pathName);
    in = new FileInputStream(file);
    out=new FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());

    byte[] buf=new byte[16384];
    int size;

    while ((size=in.read(buf)) >= 0
            && !cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
        out.write(buf, 0, size);
    }

    if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
        writeResultCallback.onWriteCancelled();
    }
    else {
        writeResultCallback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[] { PageRange.ALL_PAGES });
    }
}
catch (Exception e) {
    writeResultCallback.onWriteFailed(e.getMessage());
    Log.e("ErrorInWriting" , e.getMessage());
}
finally {
    try {
        in.close();
        out.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("ErrorInFinally" , e.getMessage());
    }
}`

the print is not correct , all the annotation and markups not appears in pdf in preview mode or even in the paper

Android's PDF rendering support is designed for PDFs created by Android's PDF-generation APIs. It is not designed for rendering or printing arbitrary PDFs obtained from anywhere. As a result, some PDF features are not going to be covered.
